# Looking for a cheat sheet or quick reference for Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning Python 3 from scratch (ie i don't know Python 2). I see that someone has asked about quick reference / cheat sheet already, but I couldn't find what I wanted in the answers to that question. Does anyone know of one? Google just throws up lots of Python 2.x stuff.
Thanks!

Comment: There are very nice and convenient cheatsheets [here](http://rgruet.free.fr/#QuickRef), but not for python 3 yet :-(. Stay tuned, who knows...

Comment: What exactly are you looking for on this cheat sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Python is well [documented](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/).

Comment: I know. I have a book and some of the online tutorials (eg "A Byte of Python". I am just looking for a cheet sheet as I am finding myself flipping back through the book to check syntax. I know this is a basic question, but I am a programming noob!

Comment: Python is well [documented](http://docs.python.org/py3k/) (Latest version)